# What CSS controls the right and left margins between these form elements in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I can't figure out what controls the margins between these inline form elements. For example the margin between the two text input fields.

EDIT:
I know how to control to alter these margins, but why is there a margin between them AT THE MOMENT. I can't find any CSS in bootstrap that is responsible for these 3 or 4px margins between them at the moment.

Comment: Can we see the site, or have some code to play around with?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline   :)

Comment: Will see and let you know .. .

Comment: see above comment mate, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the CSS selectors you will need..

**Margin the inputs/fields**:

```
.form-inline .form-group {
    margin: 0px 10px; /* Add something like this */
}
```

**Margin for the checkbox/radio button**:

```
.form-inline .radio, .form-inline .checkbox {
    margin: 0px 10px; /* Add something like this */
}
```

**Margin for the submit button:**

```
.bs-example > .btn, .bs-example > .btn-group {
    margin: 0px 10px; /* Add something like this */
}
```

**Margin for the entire inline form**

```
.bs-example {
    margin: 0px 30px; /* Add something like this */
}
```

And to answer your question, there are currently margins between elements, because that is the default. If you wish to remove them, I would suggest doing this manually by adding negative margins to the CSS controls I specified above. For instance, if you wish to remove the margins between the inputs, do this:

```
.form-inline .form-group {
    margin: 0px -3px; /* Add a negative margin to remove it*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am after the CSS that controls the current margin. WHy is there a 3 or 4px margin between the at the moment as they are on that page?

Comment: Thanks but where do they inherit them from? Firebug tells me that all the margins are 0px, yet there is some sort of margin there?

Comment: Thanks Josh, yep that's right I think! Default margins, seems like if no margins are declared there will be some space between form elements by default and thats why it doesnt show up on Firebug. Will mark your question correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The space between the inputs on Bootstrap's documentation is due to white space in the HTML. Remember that `.form-group` is set to inline block, which is sensitive to white space.

For a demonstration, see http://jsfiddle.net/kvcrawford/Rs54Q/1/

You can fix it with some CSS like the following:

```
.form-inline-space-fix .form-group {
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.form-inline-space-fix .form-group:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Watching the **HTML** code needed for the form

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2"
        placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2"
        placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

for example to put more margin after the input fields, you can:

```
form.form-inline div.form-group {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Similarly, you can do the same trick for the other elements (e.g. for the checkbox `form.form-inline div.checkbox`, for the submit button `form.form-inline button`)

Comment: Yep I understand that, but why is there a margin between them at the moment? There is like a 3 or 4px margin and I can't find the CSS that sets this margin.

Comment: @user1525612 inspecting with google chrome, I haven't find where this margin is coming from. A possible solution, like others say, is to put a negative margin (to delete the default margin).

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you are confused about. You want to know why is there a gap between two input fields.

For that the answer actually lies on the parent form class `bs-example form-inline`. There if you inspect using firebug or chromes's chromebug , then you will see a style like this : `.bs-example {margin: 0 -15px 15px;}` . Now this is the part that is controlling the space between the two individal input fields. If you block that using the fire bug or chrome bug ,then you will see that the fields actually lie one below the other and it's this margin along with `vertical-align` positioning that keeps both of them in place .